# Launch Spark-Submit - Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main

Tags: java, apache-spark

I try to execute

```
spark-submit ***.py
```

then I got

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit

After looking reference of others, I tried to locate the error inside. This is where error came from

```
exec /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java -cp '/opt/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/opt/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/*' -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit ***.py
```

and I still got the same error.

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit

Do you know the reason?

Here are my Environment Variables:

```
 J2REDIR=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_201/jre
 J2SDKDIR=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_201
 JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_201
 JRE_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/
```

Comment: Check the jars folders specified in the java command you spotted. Do they contain any jars at all ? Specifically spark*.jar files . You can also search for the jar containing the missing class with a command like `find /path/to/jars -name "*.jar" | xargs grep SparkSubmit`

Comment: Hi funkyjelly I have tried with your suggestion.
`find /opt/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars -name "*.jar" | xargs grep SparkSubmit`
It comes out the message like this:
`Binary file /opt/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-launcher_2.11-2.3.2.jar matches`
`Binary file /opt/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-core_2.11-2.3.2.jar matches`
It seems that it is able to get the SparkSubmit. However, I still can not execute my java command.